# What is the code you input to skip a line for text in javascript coding?

Tags: javascript

[image]

How would I fix this line? I just need the basic code for "skip line" or return in javascript.

Comment: You should show your code and point out what have you tried.

Comment: How does the page you linked to relate to your question? It's really not clear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: A simple google search for "javascript newline" would save you some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need seems to be an HTML tag, rather than `javascript`. In HTML you can use `<br>` tag to break a paragraph.
On Stack Overflow it is much preferable to provide a sample of your source code than a screenshot.